# Output voltage of a step-down voltage regulator (or buck converter)

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, voltage-regulator, buck, education

I've the following step-down regulator:

[image]

and I'm wondering how to get the following formula for the output voltage:

$$
V_{OUT} = \frac{T_{ON}}{T_{ON} + T_{OFF}} \, V_{IN}
$$

I calculated the current and the voltage of the inductor when the BJT is on (short-circuit) and when is off (open-circuit) in function of \$V_{OUT}\$:

\begin{equation}
V_{L} =
\begin{cases}
V_{IN} - V_{OUT}    &\text{if } 0 \leq t \leq T_{ON} \\
- V_{OUT}   &\text{if } T_{ON} < t \leq T_{OFF}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
i_{L} =
\begin{cases}
i_L(0) + \frac{V_{IN} - V_{OUT}}{L} \, t    &\text{if } 0 \leq t \leq T_{ON} \\
i_{L, \, MAX} - \frac{V_{OUT}}{L} \, (t - T_{ON})   &\text{if } T_{ON} < t \leq T_{OFF}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

[image]

It seems that the output voltage is the average value:

\begin{equation}
V_{OUT} =
\begin{cases}
V_{IN} - V_L    &\text{if } 0 \leq t \leq T_{ON} \\
- V_L   &\text{if } T_{ON} < t \leq T_{OFF}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

$$
V_{OUT} = \frac{1}{T_{ON} + T_{OFF}} \, \left( \left( V_{IN} - V_L \right) \, T_{ON} - V_L \, T_{OFF}\right) = \frac{T_{ON}}{T_{ON} + T_{OFF}} \, V_{IN} - V_L
$$

but I got the extra term \$- V_L\$.

Comment: V_L = 0 because of flux balance condition, aka steady state (delta I during a cycle = 0). So you have it right. ;)

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams \$V_L = - V_{OUT}\$ during \$T_{OFF}\$. See the plot please.

Comment: I mean V_L as in DC, or at least the average (during a cycle). I don't entirely understand your last lines, you're solving for Vout from VL but VL is dependent so solving from it is futile. Since you arrived at the same result minus that, it seems easiest to cure by adding this fact, which seems to be what you're missing, and then reduces to the expected expression.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams from the plot, the average value of \$V_L\$ during a cycle is \$V_{L} = \frac{1}{T_{ON} + T_{OFF}} \, \left( \left( V_{IN} - V_{OUT} \right) \, T_{ON} - V_{OUT} \, T_{OFF}\right) = \frac{T_{ON}}{T_{ON} + T_{OFF}} \, V_{IN} - V_{OUT}\$

Comment: Which is just the last line, adding -Vout + VL to both sides. What one piece of information on the diagram hasn't been used?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've some difficult to catch the point, can you show me why is the average value of \$V_L = 0\$ please?

Comment: VL integrated over a long time (with steady equilibrated operation) will be 0 for an ideal inductor, because the voltages of the ON and OFF phases *cancel each other* when accounting for their respective durations. This is the volt-second-balance. A real inductor will have finite VL though due to its *resistance*.

Comment: You've not used the fact about iL.  What happens when you evaluate that over a cycle? And what value must it evaluate to, in steady state (quiescent) -- what is the definition of steady state here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use various approaches to determine the dc transfer characteristic of a switching regulator. The easiest one, as you documented, uses the *inductor volt-second balance* implying that the *average* voltage across the inductor is equal to 0 V at steady-state. You could also consider a 0-A *average* current in the output capacitor also at steady-state and you would obtain the same transfer characteristic.

I have documented this technique in my last [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20SMPS%20Rev%200.32.pdf) on switching converters that I recently taught during an IEEE event. The principle is illustrated below:

[image]

Express the volt-seconds during the on-time and the volt-seconds during the off-ime. They must be equal at the converter's equilibrium. Solving for \$V_{out}\$ in the equation gives you the formula you want.

Please note that we are analyzing a perfect converter without losse (0-ohm \$r_{DS(on)}\$ switch, no freewheel diode drop, no ohmic loss on the inductor) hence the classical relationship \$V_{out}=DV_{in}\$. Start adding these extra losses and the formula complicates which each contributor weighted according to its contribution (the MOSFET during the on-time, the diode during the off-time etc.). You will find the complete formulas for the switching cells in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1949267512) on transfer functions.

Comment: Hello @VerbalKint thank you very much for your precious help.

Comment: Ciao @GennaroArguzzi, glad if it is useful!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different \$V_{L}\$ values, one (positive) value during \$T_{ON}\$ and another (negative) value during \$T_{OFF}\$. Therefore you cannot treat them as a single variable.

However over many cycles the average voltage across the inductor will become zero, so when simplifying \$\left( \left( V_{IN} - V_L \right) \, T_{ON} - V_L \, T_{OFF}\right)\$ the terms \$V_{L}\,T_{ON}\$ and \$V_{L}\,T_{OFF}\$ cancel out, leaving just \$V_{IN}\,T_{ON}\$.